# Binding TRANSFORM query in Access to a report

Tags: sql, ms-access, report, transform

Whats the best way to bind variable column names to a report field in Access when using a crosstab query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best article I found for binding columns from a crosstab query to a report is from [ewbi.develops](http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2005/01/access_sql_tran.html)'s notes.

Specifically,

```
PARAMETERS foryear Short;
TRANSFORM Sum(mytable.amount) AS total
SELECT mytable.project
FROM mytable
WHERE mytable.year In ([foryear],[foryear]+1)
GROUP BY mytable.project
PIVOT IIf(mytable.year=[foryear],"thisyear","nextyear") IN ("thisyear", "nextyear");
```

This only displays two columns that can be bound as needed.

Answer (score 1):

This page has an exhaustive example of setting up a dynamic column ("crosstab"-type) report in Access.

http://www.blueclaw-db.com/report_dynamic_crosstab_field.htm

(From google search: access transform query report)